# How to execute protractor cucumber

Tags: node.js, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I'm new to Protractor Cucumber, I have created the below scenario and execute the comment **cucumber.js**. But once I given the comment **cucumber.js** in command prompt the cucumber.js file (located in: "c:\user....\AppData\roaming\npm\cucumber.js") file got open in my notepad.

> ...\features\text.feature
>
> Feature: To test the google page
>
> Scenario: to perform search in google page
>
> Given I visit google home page
>
> When I enter keyword
>
> Then I should see the results

Could any one help to execute the feature file to get the step definition skeleton.

Comment: If you are on windows then try these command instead, cucumber-js or cucumberjs. Apparently cucumber.js command starts up some jscript instead of node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read [this](https://github.com/protractor-cucumber-framework/protractor-cucumber-framework). It's the framework you need to use CucumberJS and Protractor together.

Im the past I've created a simple [protractor-cucumber-typescript-boilerplate](https://github.com/wswebcreation/protractor-cucumber-typescript-boilerplate) to set up a protractor-cucumber testproject. Maybe it can help you going in the right direction.

Hope it helps